# How can I find all results in a PHP array, merge values, and then merge into another array

Tags: php, arrays, array-unique

Using PHP, I have an array like this:

**Array 1**

```
[
  {epid: "123", hash: "xxxxxx"},
  {epid: "456", hash: "xxxxxx"},
  {epid: "789", hash: "xxxxxx"},
  {epid: "123", hash: "xxxxxx"},
  {epid: "123", hash: "xxxxxx"},
]
```

Then, I have a second array like this:

**Array 2**

```
[
  {epid: "123", name: "This is a title"},
  {epid: "456", name: "This is a title"},
  {epid: "789", name: "This is a title"}
]
```

My goal is to get all **hash** from array one and add them to the appropriate record in array 2. From this example, the results would be:

```
[
  {epid: "123", name: "This is a title", hash: [ xxxxxx, xxxxxx, xxxxxx ] },
  {epid: "456", name: "This is a title", hash: [ xxxxxx ] },
  {epid: "789", name: "This is a title", hash: [ xxxxxx ] }
]
```

I'm sure there are multiple loops here, but for the life of me, I can't wrap my brain around it.

Comment: something like [this](https://3v4l.org/GfCLe) might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could loop through the second array and use the epid to find the indexes in the first array. Then for every index found, add the hash to the current loop item:

```
$lookup = [
    ["epid" => "123", "hash" => "xxxxxxA"],
    ["epid" => "456", "hash" => "xxxxxxB"],
    ["epid" => "789", "hash" => "xxxxxxC"],
    ["epid" => "123", "hash" => "xxxxxxD"],
    ["epid" => "123", "hash" => "xxxxxxE"],
];

$db = [
    ["epid" => "123", "name" => "This is a title"],
    ["epid" => "456", "name" => "This is a title"],
    ["epid" => "789", "name" => "This is a title"]
];

foreach($db as $i => $el) {
    $keys = array_keys(array_column($lookup, 'epid'), $el["epid"]);
    foreach($keys as $key) {
        $db[$i]["hash"][] = $lookup[$key]["hash"];
    }
}

var_dump($db);
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you don't actually have a json array, but a php array. If not, you have to convert them before.
Iterate over each entry in `array2` and filter the matching items out of the `array1`. If done, you can easily get the hashes via `array_column` and add them to `array2`.

```php
$array1 = [
  ['epid' => "123", 'hash' => "xxxxxx"],
  ['epid' => "456", 'hash' => "xxxxxx"],
  ['epid' => "789", 'hash' => "xxxxxx"],
  ['epid' => "123", 'hash' => "xxxxxx"],
  ['epid' => "123", 'hash' => "xxxxxx"],
];

$array2 = [
  ['epid' => "123", 'name' => "This is a title"],
  ['epid' => "456", 'name' => "This is a title"],
  ['epid' => "789", 'name' => "This is a title"]
];

foreach ($array2 as $key => $data) {
    $matching = array_filter($array1, static fn($filterValue) => $data['epid'] === $filterValue['epid']);
    $array2[$key]['hash'] = array_column($matching, 'hash');
}
```

Or, you could do it as short as possible with the following statement. It does exactly the same as the above, but is way more unreadable.

```php
array_walk($array2, static fn(&$value) => $value['hash'] = array_column(array_filter($array1, static fn($filterValue) => $filterValue['epid'] === $value['epid']), 'hash'));
```

Comment: Thank you, this also works perfectly! I only accepted the other response because I ran that first and it also worked.